# Given some ultrametric space $X$, is its completed metric $\hat{X}$ necessarily an ultrametric?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a lot of difficulty understanding completed metrics. In fact, I don't think I understand them at all!

How could I start showing this? I'm nearly certain that the first two properties of a metric would hold, but the third property is the one I'm not too sure about $\forall x,y,z \in X$ $$d(x,y) \leq max\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}$$

It almost seems intuitive that it would need to be an ultrametric, just because $i(X)$ is dense in $\hat{X}$, its completed metric with ($i$ an isometry), but I still can't see it...

Any clues? Much appreciated!

Comment: Let's start here: what is your textbook's definition of a completed metric space?

Comment: Sadly our textbook doesn't really give a definition of a completed metric space...

Our prof said:

$(X,i)$ consisting of a complete metric space $\hat{X}$ and an isometry $i:X \to \hat{X}$ such that $i(X)$ is dense in $\hat{X}$.. then $\hat{X}$ is the completed metric of $X$.

This seems odd to me.. I think the couple should be with $\hat{X}$ and not $X$. I really don't get it... I wish my textbook could clarify!

Comment: Would you have a textbook on hand with a clear definition of a completed metric? That would definitely be of help!

Comment: I'm planning on putting a full answer if I decide I have the time, but for now, here's my view of completions: what we're essentially doing is starting with a metric space $X$ and "adding in" the limits of any Cauchy sequences.  This bigger, filled in space, is our $\hat X$.

Comment: Now, it's "bad form" to say that we're adding points to $X$.  The "better" thing to say is that there is some already filled-in metric space $\hat X$ that has limit points for Cauchy sequences, and we can "fit $X$ in" with an isometry $i:X\to \hat X$ in such a way that, when you look at the limits of the Cauchy sequences in $i(X)$ (that is, $X$ as it sits in $\hat X$), you end up with every point in $\hat X$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, that makes a lot more sense than what I have written down. I will be sure to add this to my notes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and $z=\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are Cauchy sequences in $X$. Let $\hat x,\hat y$, and $\hat z$ be the equivalence classes of these sequences, interpreted as point of $\widehat X$. We’d like to show that $\hat d(\hat x,\hat y)\le\max\{\hat d(\hat x,\hat z),\hat d(\hat z,\hat y)\}$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ we know that $$d(x_n,y_n)\le\max\{d(x_n,z_n),d(z_n,y_n)\}\;,$$ so

$$\hat d(\hat x,\hat y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,y_n)\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\max\{d(x_n,z_n),d(z_n,y_n)\}\;.$$

If $d(\hat x,\hat z)<\hat d(\hat z,\hat y)$, then there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_n,z_n)<d(z_n,y_n)$ for all $n\ge m$, in which case

$$\hat d(\hat x,\hat y)\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\max\{d(x_n,z_n),d(z_n,y_n)\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}d(z_n,y_n)=\hat d(\hat z,\hat y)\;.$$

Similarly, $\hat d(\hat x,\hat y)\le\hat d(\hat x,\hat z)$ if $\hat d(\hat z,\hat y)<\hat d(\hat x,\hat z)$. The only remaining possibility is that $d(\hat x,\hat z)=\hat d(\hat z,\hat y)$, in which case

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\max\{d(x_n,z_n),d(z_n,y_n)\}=d(\hat x,\hat z)=\hat d(\hat z,\hat y)\;.$$

In all cases, therefore, $$\hat d(\hat x,\hat y)\le\max\{\hat d(\hat x,\hat z),\hat d(\hat z,\hat y)\}\;,$$ and $\hat d$ is an ultrametric.

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough answer! Just one thing... Do you mean $m \in \mathbb{N}$? I think its safe for me to assume so.

Comment: @Craig: I did indeed mean $m\in\Bbb N$; that was a typo. Fixed now; thanks!